# Queries about database management system

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to write these queries

- show the name of students who never Loaned Poetry books.
- show the Name of student who Loaned more than 5 books.
- show student name, book Title, issue Date, and author name  of all bookes issued books.

Query i wrote so far is not working for first task

```
SELECT 
    name       
FROM 
    students
INNER JOIN issued ON students.rollno = issued.rollno
GROUP BY 
    issued.rollno
HAVING 
    COUNT( issued.rollno )> 2
```

Comment: Please modify your question to include table data in _text_ format, and make it clear for reading.

Comment: please write your approaches and where you got stuck... is it a homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give these queries a try

```
select s.name from students s
left join issued i on (s.rollno = i.rollno)
left join bookcopy bc on (i.copyid = bc.copyid)
left join books b on (bc.bookid = b.bookid)
left join category c on (b.catid = c.catid and c.catname = 'Poetry')
where c.catid is null

select s.name, count(*) as from students s
left join issued i on (s.rollno = i.rollno)
group by s.name
having count(*) > 5

select s.name, b.title, a.authorname, i.issuedate from students s
left join issued i on (s.rollno = i.rollno)
left join bookcopy bc on (i.copyid = bc.copyid)
left join books b on (bc.bookid = b.bookid)
left join author a on (b.authorid = a.authorid);
```

Comment: I have a weird feeling I just did your homework, but if you find sql hard, I hope you study these queries and try to understand them so that you can write them yourself :)

Comment: select name, count(*) from students s
left join issued i on (s.rollno = i.rollno)
group by s.name
having count(*) > 5 this one works only one question solved thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance :) Sure, I can give it a try

Comment: btw, a tip for next time your write a question here (as stated by Tim under your original post) Write table structure and data in raw text format, much easier for people to read and understand :)

Comment: Your first question, look at the first query i wrote. its basically the same but opposite, so you would like to change "where c.catid is null" to "where c.catid is not null" and change "c.catname = 'Poetry'" to "c.catname in ('Poetry','Novel','Mathematics')"

Comment: Similar approach on second question: select a.authroname from books b
left join bookcopy bc on (b.bookid = bc.bookid)
left join issued i on (bc.copyid = i.copyid)
left join author a on (b.authorid = a.authorid)
where i.issueid is null

Comment: third question: select b.title from books b
join bookcopy bc on (b.bookid = bc.bookid)
join issued i on (bc.copyid = i.copyid)
where b.price >= 500

Comment: you are awesome . whats this reason behind your query writing skill? can you suggest me any good way to get hands on it

Comment: Thank you for your kind words :)
Mostly practice, practice, practice, a dash of google and a few years working with databases writing A LOT of queries.
But all jokes aside.
I would try small, like for example the structure you have displayed in your post, try joining books on author.
See how the result varies with different conditions and joins. If I was in your position, I would probably google sql join examples, and look at the queries that display how this work and try to match my own needs to this, once I get the hang of that, I would expand my query and try to include more tables, etc

Comment: First question you can try something like this: select b.title from books b
where b.price >= (select max(b.price) from books b join category c on (b.catid = c.catid and catname = 'Computer Science'))

Comment: May I ask, are these queries related to a school assignment?

Comment: it might not be the best suggestion of how to acquire knowledge. But never giving up and always trying different approaches and trying to learn what might be wrong if something you write gives the wrong result compared to what you expected is also a good mindset to learning something like writing sql :)

Comment: okey good to hear, not that I would have anything against helping a student, it just would feel a bit wrong writing someones homework :) Congratulations as a fresh graduate tho! :)

Comment: thanks , where are you from and whats your age and designation ?
what is your Whats app number?
and last two queries please

Comment: second question is pretty similar to the first, try this one: select * from books b
join author a on (b.authorid = a.authorid)
where b.price >= (select max(price) from books b join author a on (b.authorid = a.authorid and a.authorname = 'Deitel & Deitel'))
and a.authorname <> 'Deitel & Deitel'

Comment: I think this will solve your third question: select s.name from students s
join issued i on (s.rollno = i.rollno)
join bookcopy bc on (i.copyid  = bc.copyid)
join books b on (b.bookid = bc.bookid)
group by s.rollno
having sum(b.price) >= 500

Comment: on third there is an error message
Column 'students.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Try changing 'group by s.rollno' to 'group by s.name'

Comment: from what I can see, the second and third query looks fine to me

Comment: and what about first

Comment: on the first one you probably would want to change 'bookid=4' to 'catid=4' as that's what defines if a book is of Poetry :)

Comment: okay thank you very much . now its time to practice and understand all these joins that you have solved for me. you are great (Y)

Comment: but for catid instead of bookid i have to write a join for it i think

Comment: what was your knowledge level when you had passed graduation ?

Comment: Only if you want to have a condition that says "catname = 'Poetry' from the  table category. But since catid is already in the books table and you know Poetry is catid 4, then 'catid = 4' should work :)

Comment: Bachelors degree within IT. But I had next to nothing related to databases or sql for that matter, I think it was the worst grade I had and I basically disliked anything related to "databases". But money and career opportunities helps a lot :D

Comment: but i have to pick from totalcopy table not from books table, becuase i have to wirte query to 'display total copies of Poetry books '

Comment: hahaha whats your designation and salary. and whats app number. dont worry we will delete our messaging if this site have any kind of restriction :D

Comment: ah yes, you probably need to join bookcopy and books :)

Comment: Titled as a senior consultant working with Oracle database. I avoid any more personal information on the web, so the rest will remain a mystery, besides, I don't user whats app :)

Comment: SELECT COUNT(copyno) FROM bookcopy inner join books on bookcopy.bookid=books.bookid where catid=4   is this right now ?

Comment: Hehe, I'll be around on stackoverflow tho, So I might bump into you on other questions :D